# Error using sys.dm_db_partition_stats

Tags: sql-server

I think I have discovered an error in the SQL Server regarding the DMV sys.dm_db_partition_stats. I am testing using SQL 2016 SP1-CU8.

I am running under a security context where I am not allowed access to a specific database. In my test setup it is AdventureWorks2014

When executing the statement `SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2014.sys.dm_db_partition_stats` the query runs forever. And it does run. Looking at the instance as sysadmin I can see that the statement is executing and not just being blocked.

On the other hand when I execute a select against sys.indexes `SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2014.sys.indexes` I get the expected error message:
`Msg 916, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
The server principal "TestLogin" is not able to access the database "AdventureWorks2014" under the current security context.`

Does anyone know if the problem with sys. dm_db_partition_stats it is a known error?

Comment: So the problem is that you *can* get access when you shouldn't.

Comment: Requires VIEW DATABASE STATE permission to query the sys.dm_db_partition_stats dynamic management view. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-partition-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Yes that is the problem. I got acces but the query never ends.